# Entity Framework Generate List<SelectListItem> of unique values from model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a model called `Roles`:

```
public string CodeRole { get; set; }
public string Organisation { get; set; }
public string LabelRole { get; set; }
```

`CodeRole` and `LabelRole` contain unique values, but the `Organisation` column contains about 12 categories. I want to generate a dropdown that allows the user to filter by `Organisation`.

As a result I want to construct a query using Entity Framework that returns some form of list/array/collection I can easily convert into a `List<SelectListItem>` with both `text` and `value` equal to the distinct `Organisation` values.

I assume the query would look something like this:

```
_context.Roles.GroupBy(r=> r.Organisation)
```

This returns an `IGrouping<string,Roles>` object, but I don't know how to use the `IGrouping`.

This would allow me to pass the `List<SelectListItem>` via a `ViewBag` to a dropdown list in the view.

**Edit:** Final Solution based of Alexander Manekovskiy response

```
List<Roles> orgs = (List<DimRoles>)_context.Roles.GroupBy(f => f.Organisation).Select(r => r.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

foreach (DimRoles r in orgs) 
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = r.Organisation, Value = r.Organisation });
```

Comment: Are all of the possible values of `Organization` stored in your database somewhere?

Comment: No, they are only stored in the `Organization` column. So I want to retrive them from there

Comment: @axrwkr, I expanded the question a bit, is it more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right about GroupBy, but then you will need to select only first values from groups:

```
_context.Roles.GroupBy(r=> r.Organisation).Select(r = r.First())
```

Another possible solution is to use [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) extension method:

```
_context.Roles.Select(r=> r.Organisation).Distinct()
```

Then to get `List<SelectListItem>` you can use Select:

```
_context.Roles.GroupBy(r=> r.Organisation).Select(r => 
{ 
    var organization = r.First();
    return new SelectListItem() { Name = organization , Value = organization }
}).ToList();
```

But personally, I would prefer to have another extension method for converting `IEnumerable<T>` to `List<SelectListItem>`. This could be something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetList<TEntity>(this IEnumerable<TEntity> collection, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> keyExpression,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> valueExpression, object selectedValue = null)
{
    var keyField = keyExpression.PropertyName();
    var valueField = valueExpression.PropertyName();

    return new SelectList(collection, keyField, valueField, selectedValue).ToList();
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
_context.Roles.Distinct(new OrganizationEqualityComparer()).GetList(o => o.Organization, o => o.Organization);
```

But in this case you will need to implement `IEqualityComparer<Role>` which is pretty simple:

```
class RoleOrganizationComparer : IEqualityComparer<Role>
{
    public bool Equals(Role x, Role y)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        return x.Organization == y.Organization;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Role role)
    {
        //Check whether the object is null 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(role, null)) return 0;

        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null. 
        return role.Organization == null ? 0 : role.Organization.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks promissing: it seems to give me an `IQueryable<Roles>`, Now Do I need to loop through it and convert each entry into a SelectListItem or is there a function that can convert this for me.

Comment: Thanks, no need to appologies for an extensive answer, I appreciate the time taken. You say you prefer the seccond approach in spite of it involving more code. Why? Do you think it gives better performance?

Comment: @Chopo87 no, the performance is not better in second case, I think both approaches are equal. Second approach is more preferable in terms of Don't Repeat Yourself principle. When you have a site with lots of dropdowns you will want to centralize `IEnumerable` to `List<SelectListItem>` conversion to avoid copy and pasting.